# Android game programming - onDraw() stuttering

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, surfaceview, game-physics

I am creating an animation, and basically a ball is moving on the screen. However, I am experiencing stuttering, making the game less playable. Please have a look at my code, any pointing in the right direction is very welcome!

GameActivity.java -> starts the game loop, and handles updating.

```
Thread gameThread = new Thread(this);

public boolean running = true;

private final static int MAX_FPS = 60;
private final static int MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = 5;
private final static int FRAME_PERIOD = 1000000000/MAX_FPS;

private final static int FPS_COUNTER_REPORTTIME = 1000000000;
long lastFPSReport;
int UPS; //updates per second
public static int DPS; //draws per second

public SurfaceView gameView;

public void init() {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    Point screenDim = new Point();
    display.getRealSize(screenDim);

    width = screenDim.x;
    height = screenDim.y;

    initGame();

    gameThread.start();
}

public void initGame() {
    fingerX = (width / 2);
    fingerY = height * 0.90f;

    GamePlatform platform = new GamePlatform(fingerX, fingerY, width * 0.3f, height * 0.025f, 0, 0);
    GameBall ball = new GameBall(fingerX - 50, height * 0.8f - 50, 100, 100, 20, 20);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas = null;

    Log.d("testlog", "Starting game loop");

    lastFPSReport = System.nanoTime();

    while(running) {
        beginTime = System.nanoTime();
        framesSkipped = 0;

        try{
            canvas = gameView.getHolder().lockCanvas();

            update();

            synchronized (gameView.getHolder()) {
                gameView.postInvalidate();
            }

            timeDiff = System.nanoTime() - beginTime;
            sleeptime = (int)(FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);

            long sleeptimeMillis = (long) (Math.floor(sleeptime / 1000000));
            int sleeptimeNanos = (int)(sleeptime - (sleeptimeMillis * 1000000));

            if(sleeptime > 0) {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(sleeptimeMillis, sleeptimeNanos);
                }catch(InterruptedException e) {}
            }

            while (sleeptime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {
                //only update

                update();

                sleeptime += FRAME_PERIOD;
                framesSkipped++;
            }
        }finally {
            if(canvas != null) {
                gameView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void update() {
    UPS++;

    //FPS counter
    if(System.nanoTime() - lastFPSReport > FPS_COUNTER_REPORTTIME) {
        Log.d("testlog", "UPS: " + UPS + " | DPS: " + DPS);
        lastFPSReport = System.nanoTime();
        UPS = 0;
        DPS = 0;
    }

    //Entities
    GameEntity.updateAllEntities();
}
```

GameBall.java -> handles updating and drawing the ball, extends GameEntity.java (see below)

```
public class GameBall extends GameEntity {

public GameBall(float x, float y, float width, float height, float dx, float dy) {
    super(x, y, width, height, dx, dy, "ballMain");
}

@Override
public void update() {
    ArrayList<GameEntity> entityList = getEntityList();

    //Collision

    for(int i = 0; i < entityList.size(); i++) {
        GameEntity entity = entityList.get(i);

        if(entity.getType() != "ballMain") {
            if(this.getX() < entity.getX() + entity.getWidth() && this.getX() + this.getWidth() > entity.getX() && this.getY() < entity.getY() + entity.getHeight() && this.getY() + this.getHeight() > entity.getY()) {
                if(Math.abs(this.getDx()) < Math.abs(entity.getDx())) this.setDx(entity.getDx());
                if(Math.abs(this.getDy()) < Math.abs(entity.getDy())) this.setDy(entity.getDy());

                if(this.getDx() > 20) entity.setDx(20);
                else if(this.getDx() < -20) entity.setDx(-20);
                if(this.getDy() > 20) entity.setDy(20);
                else if(this.getDy() < -20) entity.setDy(-20);
            }
        }
    }

    this.setX(this.getX() + this.getDx());
    this.setY(this.getY() + this.getDy());

    //walls

    if(this.getX() + this.getWidth() >= GameActivity.width || this.getX() <= 0) {
        this.setDx(-this.getDx());
    }

    if(this.getY() <= 0) {
        this.setDy(-this.getDy());
    }else if(this.getY() + this.getHeight() >= GameActivity.height) {
        Log.d("testlog", "game over");
        this.setDy(-this.getDy());
    }
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    canvas.drawOval(new RectF(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getX() +      this.getWidth(), this.getY() + this.getHeight()), paint);
}
}
```

GameEntity.java:

```
public abstract class GameEntity {

float x = 0, y = 0, width = 0, height = 0;
float dx = 0, dy = 0;
String type;

static ArrayList<GameEntity> entityList = new ArrayList();

public GameEntity(float x, float y, float width, float height, float dx, float dy, String type) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
    this.type = type;

    entityList.add(this);
}

public static void updateAllEntities() {
    for(int i = 0; i < entityList.size(); i++) {
        entityList.get(i).update();
    }
}

public void update() {
    this.x += this.dx;
    this.y += this.dy;
}

public static void drawAllEntities(Canvas canvas) {
    for(int i = 0; i < entityList.size(); i++) {
        entityList.get(i).draw(canvas);
    }
}

public abstract void draw(Canvas canvas);

//Getters and Setters

public ArrayList<GameEntity> getEntityList() {
    return entityList;
}

public float getX() {
    return this.x;
}

public void setX(float x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public float getY() {
    return this.y;
}

public void setY(float y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public float getWidth() {
    return this.width;
}

public void setWidth(float width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public float getHeight() {
    return this.height;
}

public void setHeight(float height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public Point getAbsCenter() {
    return new Point((int)(this.x + (this.width / 2)), (int)(this.y + (height / 2)));
}

public Point getSurfaceCenter() {
    return new Point((int)(this.x + (this.width / 2)), (int)(this.y));
}

public float getDx() {
    return this.dx;
}

public void setDx(float speed) {
    this.dx = speed;
}

public float getDy() {
    return this.dy;
}

public void setDy(float speed) {
    this.dy = speed;
}

public String getType() {
    return this.type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
}
```

Example of the FPS counter log:

```
06-24 16:40:43.304 30689-30793/com.zenodhaene.keepitup D/testlog: UPS: 51 | DPS: 46
06-24 16:40:44.308 30689-30793/com.zenodhaene.keepitup D/testlog: UPS: 55 | DPS: 55
06-24 16:40:44.786 30689-30793/com.zenodhaene.keepitup D/testlog: game over
06-24 16:40:45.324 30689-30793/com.zenodhaene.keepitup D/testlog: UPS: 49 | DPS: 49
06-24 16:40:46.330 30689-30793/com.zenodhaene.keepitup D/testlog: UPS: 53 | DPS: 53
06-24 16:40:46.566 30689-30793/com.zenodhaene.keepitup D/testlog: game over
06-24 16:40:47.345 30689-30793/com.zenodhaene.keepitup D/testlog: UPS: 54 | DPS: 54
06-24 16:40:48.344 30689-30793/com.zenodhaene.keepitup D/testlog: game over
06-24 16:40:48.363 30689-30793/com.zenodhaene.keepitup D/testlog: UPS: 56 | DPS: 56
06-24 16:40:49.490 30689-30793/com.zenodhaene.keepitup D/testlog: UPS: 50 | DPS:  19
06-24 16:40:50.213 30689-30793/com.zenodhaene.keepitup D/testlog: game over
06-24 16:40:50.514 30689-30793/com.zenodhaene.keepitup D/testlog: UPS: 60 | DPS: 0
06-24 16:40:51.516 30689-30793/com.zenodhaene.keepitup D/testlog: UPS: 63 | DPS: 1
06-24 16:40:51.855 30689-30793/com.zenodhaene.keepitup D/testlog: game over
06-24 16:40:52.522 30689-30793/com.zenodhaene.keepitup D/testlog: UPS: 62 | DPS: 44
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you should absolutely avoid allocating / deallocating memory in your `onDraw()`.

You are using it to create a `Paint` object. Since `onDraw()` is called up to 60 times per second, the performance hit of method creation there is huge. Just move your `Paint` object to a field of the class and initialise it once. This will give you a nice save for starters.

Yan is absolutely spot on regarding the updates. Using some kind of interpolation will give you a smoother animation. There is a great [article](http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/) you can take a look at to optimise your game thread.

Comment: First of all, thank you both for answering. However, when I measure the timeDifference and devide it by the theoretical frame length (1.000.000.000 ns/60), I get that some frames are taking up to 6 times as much as the normal framelength, while others execute just fine beneath that limit. So you would think that every frame has an approximate equal length, but this is not the case...

Comment: The main goal is to calculate the interpolation - the ratio between the the time difference between two renders and your desired frame rate. Then you pass this in your update methods, so you object can access it if needed (it is almost always needed, since a constant frame rate between all devices is a myth). So, if your ball has to move with a speed of 10 between each update, and you have an interpolation of 0.2, you move it 2 points when you next render. In that way your update rate is constant and your animation is smooth.

Comment: So you are saying that I shouldn't use a frame cap? Right now, the number of frames is capped at 60 and the remaining time the thread sleeps. So only the frames with a higher-than-allowed frame time use the deltatime in the interpollation. otherwise, the interpollation is 1. there are only a few frames with a very big difference in frame time (like 1/10th of a second, instead of the normal 1/60th)

Comment: I would recommend it, yes. Capping your frames is the best way to assure that you will get a consistent frame rate across multiple devices. There is also a mechanism to check for skipped updates, so, if you start dropping, you will be able to readjust your objects accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A solution manly used in video games is to multiply every movment factor by the time between the last frame (aka delta time) you should try to go look about this